# How does Amazon SQS takes care of not sending same message to different instances of same service?

Tags: message-queue, distributed-computing, amazon-sqs, producer-consumer

I have a queue ( in this case Amazon SQS ) and there are N nodes of same service running which are consuming messages from SQS.

How can I make sure that during any point of time, not more than one nodes has read a same message from queue.

In case of Kafka, we know that, not more than one consumer from the same consumer group can be assigned to a single topic partition.  How do we make sure the same thing is handled inside Amazon SQS or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon mechanism to prevent that a message is delivered to multiple consumers is the [Visibility Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html):

> Immediately after a message is received, it remains in the queue. To prevent other consumers from processing the message again, Amazon SQS sets a visibility timeout, a period of time during which Amazon SQS prevents other consumers from receiving and processing the message. The default visibility timeout for a message is 30 seconds. The minimum is 0 seconds. The maximum is 12 hours.

After the message is received, SQS starts the timeout and for its duration, it doesn't send it again to other consumers. After the timeout ends, if the message has not been deleted, SQS makes it available again for other consumers.

But as the note says:

> For standard queues, the visibility timeout isn't a guarantee against receiving a message twice. For more information, see At-Least-Once Delivery.

If you need absolute guarantees of only once delivery, you have to option:

1. Design your application to be idempotent so that the result is
   the same if it process the same message one or more time.
2. Try
   using a SQS FIFO queue that provides [exactly once processing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html#FIFO-queues-exactly-once-processing).

Comment: Surely, there will be a need to make our system idempotent ( to avoid multiple processing of same message in different nodes) and hence make a single point of resource (db) and maintain a status that will be shared across nodes but it will eventually put up load on system in case of huge number of messages processed per unit of time. I don't want my system in such a way that it should look for db each and every time before it starts processing the message.

Comment: Further, I understand the concept of visibility time, but it will be handled at SQS end that the same message won't be ready for processing. I am kind of looking for a reason where it avoids more than one consumer to look for the message at once.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you mean with this sentence: "I am kind of looking for a reason where it avoids more than one consumer to look for the message at once." In any case I would not worry to much about excessive loading: with a properly set Visiblity Timeout is very unlikely that  SQS deliver more than once a message. And if checking the DB can put some strain on your system, maybe  you can use some other fast resource as a source of truth for checking if a message has already been processed, like Redis.

Comment: SQS won't deliver a message more than once, but, Is it possible that the same message is processed by two instances of the same service. I want to understand what happens when a consumer listen to a queue, does it create a session when receiving the message or something else to make sure that "no two instance of same service starts working on the same message". I hope this will help you in understanding what exactly I am thinking of.

Comment: That depends on your application. The services (consumers) implementation is completely up to you. SQS responsibility is only to deliver the message. What happens afterward is your (as developer / system designer ) choice.